# Sending mails using PHPmailer is not working on a live server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sendmail

If I use Gmail smtp credential working properly and after going live server it is not working. When I use godaddy web mail it not work on localhost or live server.

Here is my PHP file.

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $Cust_Email = $data->Cust_Email;
    $result = array();
require 'vendor/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail->isSMTP();                                   
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = 'orders@washbucket.info';                 
$mail->Password = '******';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
$mail->Port = 25;                                    

$mail->setFrom('orders@washbucket.info', 'Admin');
$mail->addAddress($Cust_Email);    

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'Welcome To User.';
$mail->Body    = 'This is greating from Admin';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
     $result = '_FAIL';
} else {
    $result = '_SUCCESS';
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: use this code and fetch debug data and read what wrong with your code or in your hosting  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using implicit SSL to port 25 will simply not work. Set `SMTPSecure = false`. PHPMailer will enable explicit TLS automatically if the server supports it. If I recall correctly, GoDaddy doesn't use authentication for its relay servers, so you may need to set `SMTPAuth = false` as well.